# How can the browser show an incorrect URL?

Tags: url, redirect, browser, https, auth0

I have a Vue app that uses Auth0. I'm getting this sequence of events:

- User visits https://example.com/myapp, clicks login
- User logs in at Auth0 login page
- Browser redirects to original page, now logged in, but url shown is https://example.com

This final URL is incorrect - it's definitely not possible to resolve the page at the given URL. So how is this even possible?

Comment: This is an "Address Bar Spoofing" attack. A lot vulnerabilities that allow such attacks have been found in common web browsers over the last decades. Usually it bases on special JavaScript code that performs some actions in a way that in the end the address bar shows an outdated URL.